# how to check if a date is expired or not django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that contains informations about trips and one field is a DateTimeField() like this:

```
class Voyage(models.Model):
    voyid = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key= True)
    depart = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    datedep = models.DateTimeField() #the datedep is the time and date of the trip departure
```

And the result is a list of trips so i want to output only the trips that are not expired:
(datedep > now), how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with [**`Now`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#now) for the database timestamp:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Voyage.objects.filter(datedep__gt=Now())
```